# How do I get info out of a kernel slab corruption report?

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel, fs

I'm debugging a filesystem corruption (sometimes I see symlinks pointing to "" after mount) and I enabled the usual CONFIG's in menuconfig (`EXPERT`, `KALLSYMS`, `DEBUG_KERNEL`, `DEBUG_VM`, `DEBUG_SLAB`, `DEBUG_LIST`, `DEBUG_MUTEXES`, `CC_STACKPROTECTOR`, etc) to try to get some info. This is on a 3.18-stable kernel.

With the debug kernel I sometimes see reports like this when mounting rootfs that look related:

```
Slab corruption (Tainted: P W O ): kmalloc-32 start=ac526c20, len=32
000: 00 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b  .kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
Prev obj: start=ac526c00, len=32
000: 00 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a  .ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
010: 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a a5  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.
Next obj: start=ac526c40, len=32
000: 00 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a  .ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
010: 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a a5  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.
```

I'm trying to find out what code allocated or freed (returned to the cache) the memory, or something similar.

I tested with `DEBUG_PAGEALLOC`=y and =n but I don't see "Last user" info (i.e. the stack for the kmalloc) in dmesg, which according to slab.c [1] should be printed if the memory block header has the `SLAB_STORE_USER` flag.

My question is, how can I get the alloc stacks to show in the corruption report ?

EDIT: according to slub.txt [2], this may only be possible with SLUB.

[1] http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.18.80/source/mm/slab.c#L1735

[2] https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/slub.txt

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. SLUB does give you a backtrace and redzone info. I enabled `SLUB`, `SLUB_DEBUG`, `CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG_ON`.

```
BUG kmalloc-32 (Tainted: P O ): Redzone overwritten
INFO: Allocated in custom_read+0x2c/0x9c age=1 cpu=1 pid=2856
  custom_read+0x2c/0x9c
  vfs_read+0x84/0xec
  SyS_read+0x4c/0x9c
  ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x4c
INFO: Freed in link_path_walk+0x594/0x770 age=1 cpu=1 pid=2856
  path_lookupat+0x20/0x674
  filename_lookup.isra.10+0x20/0x5c
  user_path_at_empty+0x60/0x9c
...
```

It was an off-by-one that put a \0 on the next object which was an inode->i_name.